# What is the best way of store arrays with Hibernate?

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate

I want to store an `double[]` array as `Blob` in a database with Hibernate. But when I marked the property as `Lob`, something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Lob
    double[] data;
}
```

I got the error `D cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob`. (Wherein for the `double[][]` array this is works...) So, my question is how to persis  `dobule[]` array with Hibernate?

**UPD**
I forgot the main thing, sorry... The array is big enough, some thousand of values (more specific 5000-20000 values). And I want use the `Blob` compression option from `H2` database. So, I need the `Lob`, but not `List`.

**UPD2**
Another detail, it is read-only array.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to save it as List<Double>?

Comment: I would like to know the best way to do so... to persist array of doubles. But I thought using of double[] instead of ArrayList will be more fast for the manipulations I do with the data...

Comment: In my book; working way is always better than a none working way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Lob** annotation doesn't support **double[]** type. Types supported by **@Lob** are:

- java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and java.lang.String -> persisted in database as **Clob**
- java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable types -> persisted in database as **Blob**

What you could do is create a custom serializable class and use it instead

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Lob
    DoubleArray data;
}  



public class DoubleArray implements Serializable {

    private double[] data;

    //constructor, getter and setter

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, using `@ElementCollection` for that and letting Hibernate deal with optimizations is best:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @ElementCollection
    List<Double> data;
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection